# Несколько setInterval на странице

Tags: setinterval, jquery, javascript

Есть несколько элементов к которым хочу применить функцию setInterval.
Пробовал делать через массив, но работает как-то непонятно или вообще не работает.
Вот так:

```
e.each(function () {
    t[$(this).attr('id')] = setInterval(next($(this)), 8000);
});
```

Что ещё можно попробовать? Где может быть ошибка? Или у setInterval есть какие-то особенности?

Comment: почему именно setInterval  а не setTimeout? Последний предпочтительней, так как не грузит браузер. Но может есть причины?

Comment: @zhenyab не следует пихать timeout туда, где оно не нужно.

Comment: Нет, здесь именно setInterval нужен. Слайдшоу.

Comment: @lampa - я и не пихаю. Я поэтому и спросил прежде!!! Не нужно пихать свои комментарии, где они не уместны!

Comment: @zhenyab в чём вы видите принципиальную разницу между setInterval и setTimeout в плане

> Последний предпочтительней, так как не грузит браузер

может я чего не знаю...

Comment: setInterval - вызывает функцию каждый указанный интервал, setTimeout - вызывает функцию лишь раз, через указанный промежуток времени после установки. Разница существенная!

Comment: # почему по вашему setInterval грузит браузер сильнее ?

Comment: потому что он работает непрерывно, пока не отключается. Это может вызвать перегрузку браузера. Тем более, что в данном случае интервалы устанавливаются внутри цикла.

Comment: Но этих интервалов определённое количество, и к тому же немного. Разницы в нагрузке никакой, только во времени действии. Но как я уже выше написал, у меня слайдшоу и необходимо постоянно вызывать функцию.

Comment: @zhyab сравните вот эти два кода:

    function loopMe() {
         console.log("hello");
         setTimeout(loopMe,1000);
    }
    loopMe();

------

    function loopMe() {
       console.log("hello");
    }
    setInterval(loopMe,1000);


где тут разница в нагрузке ? мало того, чтобы остановить текущий цикл, setInterval удобнее, т.к. не придется из scope первого примера экспортировать текущий id.

Comment: 1. Лучше использовать анонимную функцию в таймере, чем строку;
2. $(this).attr('id') вернет значение атрибута - строку или undefined
Что тогда будет означать t['some_string'] или t[undefined]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то функция `next` принимает на вход jQuery коллекцию, если это правда, то ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
e.each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);

    // для 90% браузеров
    t[$el.attr('id')] = setInterval(next.bind(null, $el), 8000);

    // для всех
    t[$el.attr('id')] = setInterval(function (){
        next($el);
    }, 8000);
});
```

Comment: Да такой вариант я пробовал, но в итоге пришёл к другому способу.
И корректней записать тогда так: 
    
    t[$(this).attr('id')] = setInterval(next, 8000, $(this));

Comment: LOL, [setInterval][1]/[setTimeout][2] — принимают только два параметра и если ваш код работает, то может смело его убирать.

[setInterval][1]: http://javascript.ru/setInterval
[setTimeout][2]: http://javascript.ru/setTimeout

Comment: @RubaXa https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: В каком смысле убирать? Код? Да всё работает, и в IE10, и в IE9. Я нашёл, что setInterval может принимать 3 и больше параметров. Вот ссылка http://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval.

Comment: Признаю ошибку, сосем забыл об этой возможности.

Comment: @lampa, @Святослав: ради справедливости, я всё же прав, передача параметров таким способом не кроссбраузерна, в IE < 9 она не работает.

Comment: @RubaXa ну вы полностью отрицали эту возможность)

Comment: @lampa, привычка. Не использую то, что не работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.each(function () {
    var that = this;
    t[$(this).attr('id')] = setInterval(next($(that)), 8000);
});
```

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает что надо

    setInterval(function(){next.apply($(that));}, 8000);

Comment: @eicto и мне. Выходные же, ошибочка вышла!